# mysql ON CONFLICT IGNORE

Tags: mysql

I started with sqlite3 and now have to make the switch to mysql. My create table code structure for sqlite3 is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players(
          "Name" TEXT,
          "B/T" TEXT,
          "Ht" TEXT,
          "Wt" TEXT,
          "DOB" TEXT,         
          UNIQUE (Name, DOB) ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
```

I am using a python script I have that appends from a data_frame to the db.table.  The UNIQUE, ON CONFLICT IGNORE works the way i need it to for never appending duplicates. My issue is I cannot seem to get it to work in mysql. I have been searching for any ideas on how I can get the same result from that one line in mysql. My current mysql line that errors:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS players(              
          Name VARCHAR(30),
          `B/T` VARCHAR(5),
          Ht VARCHAR(5),
          Wt VARCHAR(5),
          DOB VARCHAR(11),
          UNIQUE (Name, DOB) ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
```

Any solution or criticism much appreciated!

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing in MySQL. But you can rewrite your INSERT statements to `INSERT IGNORE ..` which will ignore duplicate inserts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL it's left to the discretion of the query how you want to handle duplicates. [`INSERT IGNORE ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) is the the preferred way to handle this.

Note that `UNIQUE` indexes do not trigger on `NULL` values because `NULL=NULL` is false.

Comment: Technically, of course, the reason is that that "`null = null` is not true."  It's also not false.  It's still null.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL supports [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) which you can use to ignore duplicate inserts by doing a no-op.

This avoids the pitfalls of `INSERT IGNORE` which ignores some other issues than duplicate keys, which often leads to undetected bugs (for instance [data conversion issues](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html#:%7E:text=Data%20conversions%20that%20would%20trigger%20errors%20abort%20the%20statement%20if%20IGNORE%20is%20not%20specified.%20With%20IGNORE%2C%20invalid%20values%20are%20adjusted%20to%20the%20closest%20values%20and%20inserted%3B%20warnings%20are%20produced%20but%20the%20statement%20does%20not%20abort))